# Creating Plugin Management System

Tags: c, linux, x11

What options do I have as far as creating a plugin management system for something such as [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/). What I am interested in is creating a system for Conky that would allow me to create new functions and add them through a shared library. This I feel would make it easier to create new configurations and variables for Conky without the need to recompile from source and allow these new functions to be shared independent of Conky. What are some general starting points for creating a system such as this? Are shared libraries the best option or are there better one.

I realize Conky already has an ability similar to this with the ability to call a system shell and return whatever is required, however many of the functions I would like to add would bog down Conky unless directly written in.

Comment: First starting point: learn how to use dlopen()

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to dlopen().

Here is some nice tutorial: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

I did something similar to an IRC bot I wrote up from scratch in C. I used dlopen() to do such a thing.
The bot could compile it's own new modules and load them while runtime :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering conky already uses GLib for some of its modules, you might as well take a look at GLib's module system (GModule): http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html

Another handy library that's based on that is libpeas: http://developer.gnome.org/libpeas/stable/